# Updating custom Android app

Tags: android

My customer wants the android app to update itself automatically whenever a change is made. They do not want to publish the app in the android market. For the first time, the app will be installed using the Android SDK or the numerous other ways to install.

How do I ensure that the app is automatically upgraded whenever bug fixes or features are added. If not automatically, a button from the app is also ok

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create an "updater" application. This application will monitor a remote server for updates and if it finds one, it will install the apk programmatically. Read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967669/android-install-apk-programmatically) for directions on how you can install an apk programmatically. You will easily find more information regarding this topic on the net.

Comment: re: easily find more info. A few choice resources would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use Pushlink. http://www.push-link.com

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in following ways :
1. a push notification mechanism 
2. server pooling on each start / time interval
3. Push SMS

to update the client application.

Answer (score 0):

If your client is using Google Apps you can create a private Google play channel for your organization. There you can publish the apps only for your users to see. I know that you explicitly said that this is not an option, but it's, by far, the best option (although it's not free).

http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2494992

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can update your app programmatically:

- download new version of your app (*.apk) to a local storage of
  Android device
- run new Intent for update app

```
    Intent intentInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
            .setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file:///path/to/new_app.apk"), 
                            "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intentInstall);
```

- remove downloaded *.apk

See also [Android App Version Update service without releasing it to marketplace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25316078/android-app-version-update-service-without-releasing-it-to-marketplace)